# Strings as a foreign key in Laravel 7 Not Set

Tags: php, laravel, string, foreign-keys

***Strings Error With Foreign Keys***

ID is working fine name, lastname, email is having a problem initializing.
*"Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `login_logs` add constraint  `login_logs_name_foreign` foreign key (`name`) references `users` (`name`))
*

**User Table:**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('lastname');
        $table->string('mobile');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('image')->default('avatar.png');
        $table->integer('status')->default(2);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

**Logs_Table**

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('login_logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->bigInteger('id_user')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('lastname');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->timestamps();


$table->foreign('id_user')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('name')->references('name')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('lastname')->references('lastname')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('email')->references('email')->on('users');



    });
}
```

Comment: String as a foreign key? I think you posted the wrong code

Comment: @sta this is login_logs, I am trying to get name, Lastname and email as a foreign key from users table, a little mistake is like this but still does not work



            $table->foreign('id_user')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('name')->references('name')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('lastname')->references('lastname')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('lastname')->references('lastname')->on('users');`

Comment: This code looks very odd. you have 4 foreign keys in one table referencing 4 fields in another table. Normally referencing only the identifier on the other table should be enough. I'm not even sure you can have a foreign key to a non-unique field (it's allowed with certain SQL extensions but even then it's discouraged)

Comment: @apokryfos I understand, Thank you!